# What is the best practice adding int range to Queue<int>

Tags: c#

I need to create some queue that hold the free location of an Array.
So i hold some queue that contain the next free location - and i want to know what is the effective way to add the int range to this queue ?

This is the code - but i not sure that this is the best practice

```
 Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
 for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
 {
      queue.Enqueue(i);
 }
```

Comment: you mean you want to know if you can do it in one line? is that is?

Comment: this is academic question - this is not a question of write or wrong     :) and yes .. i would like to have is in one line

Comment: That's a pretty expensive way of doing things - why do you want to explicitly store every free location? Context is key if you want a "best practice" response. For example, what is the life-cycle of the contents here? Would a circular buffer be sufficient? What is the data? Would a simple "last used offset, now scan for a null" be OK? (in many cases that would work fine - and even then the "last used offset" is just an optimisation)

Comment: Marc, i have an array that hold 10000 cells - i need to find the location of the next free cell and this is the reason i want to use this queue. the data in the array is some object class.  i must avoid scanning of the object array

Comment: If (A[I] != 1) then its a free location....

Comment: Why do you think that scanning (from last known offset) is particularly terrible? In most applications that will work fine. Again: explicitly storing 10k indices is ... A bit bizarre, and certainly very unusual. You didn't answer any of my questions about what you are actually doing, life-cycles, etc

Comment: @Yanshof You might also consider using some form of [free list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it will be more *efficient*, but is sure short syntactically:

```
var queue = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10000));
```

---

Alternatively, try benchmarking:

```
var queue = new Queue<int>(10000);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    queue.Enqueue(i);
```

Note the use of *capacity* parameter in the queue constructor, which should prevent reallocations. Unfortunately there is no "EnqueueRange", so we must use loop with Enqueue here.

Answer (score 1):

You might like

```
var queue = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10000));
```

but it is just a matter of taste.